# which css style handles the click event on a button? other than hover

Tags: html, css

I see this site that has a button, when I hover over it the background changes.

When I click on the button, the button shading inverts i.e. reacts to the click event.

Which CSS style is this?  I know :hover is for hover, but what about a click?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet it's javascript doing image manipulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS does not handle events.

You're looking for the `:active` pseudo class, which is only for the A-tag, not buttons. You can style A tags to look like buttons as well though.

See: http://w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: Dude, you're three years late on that tip.

Comment: ...or to be smarmy, apparently.

Answer (score 12):

CSS3 does handle activation events now (2013).

The :active pseudo-class is working on any css selector like BUTTONs, not just A tags.

*CSS3 STYLE*

```
p { margin: 2em; }
button { background-color: White; color: SteelBlue; }
button:hover { background-color: LightSteelBlue; }
button:active { background-color: SteelBlue; color: White; }
```

*HTML5*

```
    <p>
        <button>test button with :active pseudo-class</button>
    </p>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wp86u/

See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp (content changed since Diodeus answer)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking at is the browser's default styles for the :active pseudo-class, which also applies to keyboard input on a button (try tabbing to it and pressing the spacebar).

These pseudo-classes do NOT just apply to the anchor element, it's a common misconception caused by old versions of IE not supporting them on anything other than the anchor element.